# How to upload image to existing fan page if the user is not the administrator fan page?

Tags: php, facebook, upload, facebook-page

This code return "invalid album id".
if the user is admin fan page then it works. 
But I need that all users can upload photos through the app in fan page album.

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => '553412241404428',
    'secret' => '...',
    'fileUpload' => true, // optional
    'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
    'cookie' => true
);
// exist ALBUM from URL
$ALBUM_ID = "765349256813004";

$filename = $_GET['file'];

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

if(!$user = $facebook->getUser()) {
    echo "<a target='_blank' href='".$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_actions,publish_stream,user_photos,email,read_stream,manage_pages,user_groups'))."'>Auth</a>";
    exit;
}
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();



$FILE_PATH = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."facebook/uploads/".$filename;
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$args['access_token'] = $access_token;


$data = $facebook->api('/'. $ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);exit;
```

Comment: So you want *anyone* to be able to upload photos to a Facebook page?

Comment: Yes, any user through the application facebook to Album fan page

Comment: Do you not think it’s a security feature that not just any one can upload an album to a Facebook page? Otherwise developers could just spam the hell out of it, uploading their own graphics to other users’ pages.

Comment: Martin is right. You can't do that/